# Wordpress, Genesis theme, streamline pro, How to add an extra .PHP file?

Tags: genesis

I would like to create a new formhandler.php file where I can collect the info from a form on a page in the streamline pro theme on the genesis framework. I am looking at appearance-> editor -> streamline pro theme. I see a list of php files:

Templates

- front-page.php
- Theme functions (function.php)
- theme-defaults.php (lib/theme-defaults.php)
- Landing page templates (page_landing.php)

Now my question is: How do I add another .php file under this? (or anywhere else) to gather the form info using the PHP POST Method. Other suggestions are welcome. Should I do this by building a custom plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You put files in your Child theme, how to add new template, take a look here https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/#Custom_Page_Template, and here also
http://www.carriedils.com/custom-page-template-genesis/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I did not mean a page template.